# Persistence of Android KeyStore and access permissions to key material

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, trustzone

How persistent is the Android KeyStore, whether hardware-backed (via TrustZone) or not? Do the keys that are generated within the KeyStore get deleted after the creating app is uninstalled?

Do they also get deleted upon a factory reset? (especially hardware-backed ones, not sure if a factory reset also wipes TrustZone). Can other apps access the key material (use/read them) if they know the alias?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like key material within the KeyStore doesn't survive a factory reset, and gets wiped once the app creating it is uninstalled. Additionally, depending on the Android version and key configuration, it might also get wiped upon device lockscreen modifications. [Source](https://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/)